# How to pass in / use .Class/Object as method parameter

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I have various CSV files representing different classes that need to be added to Cloud FireStore. I use the CSV Routines library to convert csv records from a specific csv file to objects of a specific class, and then I add each object to a specific Cloud FireStore collection

This code works

```
try {
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getAssets()
                .open("fullvar3.csv"));

        CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines();

        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        for (Variety v : routines.iterate(Variety.class, is)) {
            firestore.collection("/static/test/DFLKJDF39494/varieties").add(v);
        }
    } catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Exception");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

There are quite a few csv files - each representing a different class. There are also different corresponding collections in Cloud FireStore to which the contents must be added.

I'd like to create a single method that can be called with parameters for each CSV File/Class/Cloud Firestore tuple. Passing in the csv file name and Cloud Firestore Collection path is easy enough, but I'm having trouble with the class. It comes into play twice in the for-each loop - once as an object and once as a '.class' thing. Here is what I have so far (doesn't compile).

```
public void addToCloudStore(String filename, String path, Class cl){
    try {
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getAssets()
                .open(filename));

        CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines();
        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Object obj = new Object();
        cl.cast(obj);
        for (obj : routines.iterate(cl, is)) {
            firestore.collection(path).add(obj);
        }
    } catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Exception");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can this be modified to work?

Comment: I don't have a project with the necessary libraries to try this myself but the first thing I would try is changing `Class` to `Class<?>` and the `for` loop to `for (var obj : ...`. The first part might not be necessary; the for loop is definitely not syntactically correct without some type, even type inferencing, for the loop variable. Oh, and the `new Object()` part is completely unneeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David Conrad for the tips

Here is a working solution

```
 public void addToCloudStore(String filename, String path, Class<?> cl){
    try {
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getAssets()
                .open(filename));
        CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines();
        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        for (Object obj : routines.iterate(cl, is)) {
            firestore.collection(path).add(obj);
        }

    } catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Exception");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but just out of curiosity, is it possible to make it so that the static type of obj is whatever type cl represents instead of Object?